# How to fix Instantiate killing my performance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am [instantiating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) two sets of 50 [GameObjects](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) each.

```
private Enemy e1, 
              e2;

private Stack stack1, 
              stack2;


for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    stack1.Push(Instantiate(e1));

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
   stack2.Push(Instantiate(e2));
```

This code slows down my scene loading time. **Is there a better way to do this?**

---

#### Important Information

I use the objects right away after loading the scene. I store re use them throughout all my scenes so I never destroy them. Each object has very Little if any code in the Awake().

Comment: Are sure about trying to instantiating all the objects in one single frame. I guess that's why the performance is affected. Try to separate the instantiating to multiple frames.

Comment: Stack? So you are not using all the 100 instantiated objects simultaneously. Right?

Comment: @SergeyKrusch I use more than half of them at a time.

Comment: I see. Firstly this is how computers work: doing something 100 times takes more time, than doing something 0 times. Secondly it depends on the objects that you are instantiating. What is `Enemy`? What is going on in `Awake`, `OnEnable`?

Comment: Do you need them right away after the scene loaded? Maybe you don't need all of immediately?

Comment: @Leosori yes I need them right away after the scene is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Instantiate the Objects right when your scene starts, deactivate them and only activate them when needed. That way you get the lag at the start when it is usually no problem to wait a couple of seconds.

Another way is to Instantiate GameObjects untill you reach a time Value in milliseconds that you set and then stop untill the next frame. This may or may not work depending on what you are doing.

If the actual objects you are instantiating are used frequently but only for a short duration you can do it like my first approach and reuse them when needed. Google "unity Object Pool" for that and you get a couple of good results.